# Does exist some Java8 convenient manner to incr a property of an object?

Tags: java, java-8, setter

Latest project I used java8 , found it's very convenient to process Collection type， it gave me great surprise. But suddenly feel some conventional syntax are so cumbersome, for example I have an Object called BuyerOrderCountStats, every time buyer commit an order, will increase his order count,

```
BuyerOrderCountStats bocs = ...;
bocs.setOrderCount(bocs.getOrderCount()+1);
```

Is there some convenient manner for this situation in java 8 which I don't know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Tagir Valeev’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33664455/2711488) points you into the right direction. Whenever there is a business logic to model, you should avoid `public` getters and setters (especially setters) and try to provide appropriate business logic specific update operations.

But since you asked about properties and Java 8 features in general, it’s worth noting that there is an alternative, if you still want (or need) to allow external update operations for a property:

```
class BuyerOrderCountStats {
    private int orderCount;

    // may still have getters and setters

    public void updateOrderCount(IntUnaryOperator op) {
        orderCount=op.applyAsInt(orderCount);
    }
}
```

Then you may change the property like:

```
BuyerOrderCountStats stats= …
stats.updateOrderCount(count -> count+1 );
```

You only have to keep in mind, that you can’t use the postfix `++` here as `count++` only modifies the lambda expression’s parameter but returns the old value. A prefix increment, i.e. `++count`, would work here as it evaluates to the result, but the modification of the parameter would be pointless and misleading. Thus, don’t use neither `++` nor `+=` here, use always `+` like in the above example. The same applies to other operators.

The `updateProperty` method can verify whether the result is within the legal range for the property before making a change just like `setProperty` can do. One advantage of the `updateProperty` method is, that it can provide locking if needed to avoid concurrent updates. This is something, a get-modify-set roundtrip cannot provide.

Comment: Thanks! if use normal getter/setter and guarantee thread safe, should use synchronized decorate. You mean only use updateProperty doesn't need synchronized decorate still could guarantee thread safe?

Comment: No, the point is, having thread safe getter and setter does not prevent updates *between* the invocations of the getter and the setter. Thus, updates using the old value read via getter and writing the computed value via setter still need an addition external locking operation, even if the two methods itself are thread-safe. In contrast, the update method *can* be made thread-safe, holding the lock during the entire evaluation of the lambda expression. It still has to do so if needed, e.g. by declaring the method `synchronized`. But no external synchronization at the caller is required.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing very special exists in java-8 which would help to solve your problem. However you may design your class (even in Java 1.0) to fit the business logic better. Remove `setOrderCount` method and replace it with `addOrder()`:

```
class BuyerOrderCountStats {
    private int orderCount;

    public void addOrder() {
        orderCount++;
    }
}
```

In many cases instead of plain setters you can create better business-logic specific methods which modify the object state.